# Changing visibility of inner a tag

Tags: javascript

I have a class

```
 .nav-part a{ display:block;}
```

How can I change the display by JavaScript to none

I couldn't find any way using just JavaScript and accessing a's visibility and changing the visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it via pure js code

```
document.querySelector('.nav-part a').style.display = 'none'
```

below is a reference for you

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('click',() => {
  
  let link = document.querySelector('.nav-part a')
  link.style.display = 'none'

})
```

```css
.nav-part a{ display:block;}
```

```html
<div class ="nav-part">
  div data
 <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>

<button>Button</button>
```